# iOS Swift, Enum CaseIterable extension

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to write an extension for an enum that is `CaseIterable` so that i can get an array of the raw values instead of the cases, Im not entirely sure how to do that though

```
extension CaseIterable {

    static var allValues: [String] {
        get {
            return allCases.map({ option -> String in
                return option.rawValue
            })
        }
    }
}
```

i need to add a where clause somehow, if i dont have a where clause i get an error saying `'map' produces '[T]', not the expected contextual result type '[String]'`

Anyone know if there is a good way of going about this?

my enums i want this function to work on look a bit like this

```
enum TypeOptions: String, CaseIterable {
    case All = "all"
    case Article = "article"
    case Show = "show"
}
```

Comment: Please use camel case for enum cases (https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#conventions)

Comment: ... *lower* camel case :)

Comment: Noted thank you, old habits :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not all enumeration types have an associated `RawValue`, and if they have then it is not necessarily a `String`.

Therefore you need to restrict the extension to enumeration types which are `RawRepresentable`, and define the return value as an array of `RawValue`:

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: RawRepresentable {

    static var allValues: [RawValue] {
        return allCases.map { $0.rawValue }
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
enum TypeOptions: String, CaseIterable {
    case all
    case article
    case show
    case unknown = "?"
}
print(TypeOptions.allValues) // ["all", "article", "show", "?" ]

enum IntOptions: Int, CaseIterable {
    case a = 1
    case b = 4
}
print(IntOptions.allValues) // [1, 4]

enum Foo: CaseIterable {
    case a
    case b
}
// This does not compile:
print(Foo.allValues) // error: Type 'Foo' does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'
```